# How to validate dialog fields without closing the dialog window?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I would like to validate the `DialogField` value without closing the dialog window (not in closeOK).
I'm using Dynamics 365 FFO.

```
class myClassCaller
{
    MyClassDialog::MyPromtDialog(`parameters`);
}


class MyClassDialog 
{
  static container MyPromtDialog(`parameters`)
  {
    DialogField    myDialogField;
    Dialog         dialog;

   ..........

   myDialogField = dialog.addField(extendedtypestr(MYEDT),"Label","Label");

  **// I would like to check/validate the DialogField value**

   if (! dialog.run())
   return ['', ''];

   .....
   return localContainer;
}
```

There is any way to intercept the value insert in to `myDialogField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to look at `registerOverrideMethod`.

You can see an example here -
https://daxonline.org/1559-simple-dialog-with-field-validation-and-control-override-method.html

You would do something like

> `myDialogField.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, validate), methodStr(YourClass, yourValidateMethod), this);`

where `this` is the object where `yourValidateMethod` exists.

Then you create a method similar to:

```
public boolean yourValidateMethod(FormControl _formControl)
{
    ...
}
```